# Rust trait bounds with types

Tags: generics, rust, traits

I was reading the [hyperium/http](http://github.com/hyperium/http) source code and I found [this](https://github.com/hyperium/http/blob/090badcf00426abe582332d19abf3ea0fd9db5fe/src/request.rs#L253):

```
pub fn put<T>(uri: T) -> Builder
 where
    Uri: TryFrom<T>,
    <Uri as TryFrom<T>>::Error: Into<crate::Error>,

{
    Builder::new().method(Method::PUT).uri(uri)
}
```

In this snippet, `Uri` is a type and `T` a generic element. 
I have always seen the construction `where T: SomeTrait`, but not `SomeType: SomeTrait<T>`.
Does this construction have a name and is it documented somewhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quoting https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/trait-bounds.html#higher-ranked-trait-bounds:

> Bounds on an item must be satisfied when using the item. When type
>   checking and borrow checking a generic item, the bounds can be used to
>   determine that a trait is implemented for a type. For example, given
>   `Ty: Trait`
>
> In the body of a generic function, methods from `Trait` can be called on `Ty` values. Likewise associated constants on the `Trait` can be
>   used.
>       Associated types from `Trait` can be used.
>       Generic functions and types with a `T: Trait` bounds can be used with `Ty` being used for `T`.

Nothing states that `Ty` is a type parameter (and not a fixed type). So I would say it is simply a trait bound, albeit admittedly not very often encountered in Rust tutorials.